# javascript timer for multiple auction item not working with php

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

I'm trying to implement a countdown timer for the online auction project, But it's only working for one item displayed. Here is the code:

```
 <?php
 $result=mysql_query("select * from `date`")or die(mysql_error());

while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
$then = $row['date'];
$now = time();
$thenTimestamp = strtotime($then) + strtotime($now);
$difference = $thenTimestamp - $now;
echo '<script type="text/javascript">

var seconds ='.$difference.';
function secondPassed() {
var hours=Math.round(seconds / 3600);
var minutes = Math.round(((seconds - 30)/60)%60);
var remainingSeconds = seconds % 60;

document.getElementById("countdown").innerHTML = hours+ ":"+ minutes + ":" +   remainingSeconds;

if (seconds == 0) {
  //  clearInterval(countdownTimer);
   document.getElementById("countdown").innerHTML = "Buzz Buzz";
} else {
    seconds--;
}
}
setInterval("secondPassed()", 1000);
  </script>
 <body>
 <span id="countdown"></span>
</body>';
}
?>
```

I have to submit my project on online auction by tomorrow. so, i need the solution. please help me out.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: your question/problem?

Comment: above script work's perfect for one auction. if i place more than one auction it shows timer for only last added auction. not for all?

Comment: Simply, you have to place every auction in separate HTML element and encapsulate your code in a function that takes that element id or class name to run the counter for it.

Comment: can you please give an demo for that?

Comment: i tried above code but it works for only one auction.